# Как выполнить код спустя время после того как программа была запущена? (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

написал вот такой код:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::ops()
{
    ui->label->setText("tteexxtt");
}

QTimer::singleShot(3000, this, &MainWindow::ops);
```

и добавил в mainwindow.h:

```
private slots:
    void ops();
```

и поидеи программа должна запускаться, потом должен пройти отсчет 3 секунды и текст в label должен поменяться на tteexxtt, но я получаю ошибки:

```
mainwindow.cpp:22:9: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
mainwindow.cpp:22:26: Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function
mainwindow.cpp:22:45: 'ops' is a private member of 'MainWindow'
mainwindow.h:21:10: declared private here
mainwindow.cpp:21: ошибка: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
```

как можно устранить данные ошибки?

Comment: Вынесите определение метода `ops()` за пределы конструктора.

Comment: если я вынесу определение метода ops() из конструктора будет еще больше ошибок

Comment: Цепани слотом с контекстом

Comment: разшифруйте пожалуйста

Comment: Ну надо комп включать....

Comment: а если серьезно?

Comment: Вам компилятор говорит, что определение функций в данном месте не поддерживается. Вынесите его за пределы, `private:` измените на `private slots:`, и покажите ошибки, если они останутся.

Comment: @needKVAS пересмотрите мой вопрос, я сделал все так как вы имели ввиду?

Comment: А `QTimer::singleShot(3000, this, &MainWindow::ops);` верните где был. С ним всё нормально было.

Comment: Спасибо, ошибки исправлены